# How to filter a kendo ui datasource serverside

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I use a kendo ui scheduler with AngularJS. When the scheduler initially is loaded, the application does not use any filters. When the scheduler is shown to the user, the user must be able to set some filters and submit these filters to the web api. But I'm not able to receive the parameters.

The value of requestStatus can be populated by a multi select:

```
<select ng-model="requestStatus" id="requestStatus" name="requestStatus" class="form-control" multiple>
<option value="0" label="Open">Open/option>
<option value="1" label="Closed">Closed</option>
```

```
<button ng-click="filterPlanboard()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

My angularjs Controller is like this:

```
    var requestStatus = "";
    $scope.filterPlanboard = function () {
                console.log($scope.requestStatus);
                var requestStatus = $scope.requestStatus;
                console.log(requestStatus); //shows: Array ["0","1"] when all items are selected
                $scope.schedulerOptions.dataSource.read({
                    "Status": requestStatus,
                    "Type": ["70"]
                });
                //$scope.schedulerOptions.refresh();

        };
    $scope.$watch("planboardId", function () {

        var schedulerDs = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
            //batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost:51714/api/Events/Read/" + $scope.planboardId,//"//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //data: kendo.stringify({"Color": "Green"}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "http://localhost:51714/api/Events/Update",//"//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/update",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {

                    }
                    else if (operation === "update") {
                        return kendo.stringify({ planboardId: $scope.planboardId, planboardEvent: options });
                    }

                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "taskId",
                    fields: {
                        taskId: { from: "Id" },
                        title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                        end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                        //startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        //endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        description: { from: "Description" },
                        //recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                        //recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                        //recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                        ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                        eventColor: { from: "EventColor", defaultValue: "#333333" }
                        //isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.schedulerOptions = {
                date: new Date("2016/6/26"),
                startTime: new Date("2016/6/26 07:00 AM"),
                height: 600,
                views: planboardViewService.getViews(),
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                eventTemplate: $('#event-template').html(),
                ataSource: schedulerDs,
                resources: [
                               {
                                   field: "ownerId",
                                   name: "Owner",
                                   title: "Owner",
                                   dataSource: [
                                       { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                                       { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                                       { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };
```

My Web Api is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<PlanboardEventViewModel> Read(int id, [FromBody] FilterModel filterModel)
{
    return _peRepo.GetEvents(id);
}
```

And my FilterModel:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string Status {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

When I press the submit button, I can see in fiddler the following json string is shown (in TextView) :

```
{"Status":["0","1"],"Type":["70"]}
```